# C# list/array of Images to JS

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, image, api

I have c# API where download image from SQL and convert to Image class object and return Image[], after that i want show my images in JS, and save to local storage, but images not showing, because src of images are [object Object] [JavaScript images src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmBGR.png). How can extract image from Array?

**C# API**

```
        try
        {
            List<Image> photoList = new List<Image>();
            sqlConnection.Open();
            byte[] imgArray;
            Image fullImage;
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            int i = dr.FieldCount;
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    imgArray = (byte[])dr["Image"];
                    fullImage = ByteArrayToImage(imgArray);

                    photoList.Add(fullImage);
                }
            }
            Image[] imagesArray;
            imagesArray = photoList.ToArray();
            return imagesArray;
        }
```

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/fileupload/download' + "?" + "name=" + name,
    timeout: 0,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            console.log(response[i]);
            var Img = document.createElement('img');
            Img.src = response[i];
            parent.appendChild(Img);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the value of `response`?

Comment: value of `response = undefined` but `response are Array(2)`

Comment: How can it be both undefined and an array?

Comment: `console.log(response) = Array(2)` and `console.log(response.value) = undefined`

Comment: `.value` is not a standard array property. Try looping through the array instead?

Comment: looping through the array write `Object` and `Object`